# Issue on type validation with API Platform / Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com, symfony6

I'm trying to use validation on type to have a personalized message error.

I use API Platform v3.1.11 and Symfony 6.2.10

I put the parameter to disable the type enforcement :

```
#[ApiResource(
    denormalizationContext: ['disable_type_enforcement' => true]
)]
```

```
    #[ORM\Column]
    #[Assert\NotBlank(message:"Sender zipcode is required.")] 
    #[Assert\Type(type:"int",message:"Sender zipcode is in wrong format.")]   
    private ?int $sender_zipcode = null;

    public function getSenderZipcode(): ?int
    {
        return $this->sender_zipcode;
    }

    public function setSenderZipcode($sender_zipcode): self
    {
        $this->sender_zipcode = $sender_zipcode;

        return $this;
    }
```

When I put my POST request with a string value in sender_zipcode, I got this message error

```
    "hydra:description": "Failed to denormalize attribute \"senderZipcode\" value for class \"App\\Entity\\Shipment\": Expected argument of type \"?int\", \"string\" given at property path \"senderZipcode\".",
```

Instead of "Sender zipcode is in wrong format."

Thanks

Comment: The ObjectNormalizer tries to set the value via the setter. The value will be of type string, probably already in the JSON. But the definition of the property is `?int`. If you remove `?int` from the property, it should work. But then you have not a type declaration. You could set `null|string|int` at the property. In the getter, you then make a type cast to int.